# Import image to python program

Tags: image, file

I am trying to run a simple python program that loads an image:

```
import Image
import os.path

script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('__file__'))
im = Image.open(os.path.join(script_dir, 'test.jpg'))

img.show()
```

I keep getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/projects/testimage.py", line 5, in <module>
    im = Image.open(os.path.join(script_dir, 'test.jpg'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1952, in open
    fp = __builtin__.open(fp, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pi/projects/test.jpg'
```

I have the jpg saved in that directory but nothing seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that it works if you remove the ".jpg" at the end of the file name.